# Rewriterule conflict in a .htaccess file using mod_rewrite.c

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using mod_rewrite for clean URL's. Until now, everything is working fine :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule (.*) application.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But then, I just try to add another rule that transforms the `www.mysite.com` urls `mysite.com` , using the following :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Results : when I access `mysite.com` it's fine, but when accessing `www.mysite.com` , the URL becomes an ugly `mysite.com/application.php?request=`

How can I adjust my .htaccess file so there is no conflicts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the redirect rule is **before** the routing rule, otherwise the routing rule gets applied, the rewrite engine loops (will continue to loop until the URI stops changing) and then the redirect happens, on the rewritten URI.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule (.*) application.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```